# Why can't Ubuntu 14.04 access the files on my Android phone?

Tags: usb, android, samsung

I just downloaded and installed 14.04 to replace a Xubuntu 14.10 that has been crashing on every reboot. Now, with nothing else installed, I am no longer able to communicate with my Samsung S4! When plugging in my phone, I immediately get

> Unable to mount SAMSUNG Android  Unable to open MTP device
>   '[usb:003,007]'

I was able to read my phone with no issue whatsoever in Xubuntu.  I just discovered this one today; I've been hesitant to plug my phone into this installation because of the `read only file system` issues I've been having, but I plugged it in out of habit a little while ago, and this is something new.

Another post on here said the issue is fixed by changing cables; I have tried 3, all of which work just fine on windows, and one of which is the one that was working fine with Xubuntu. And yes, the phone is in USB debug mode. Any hints on where to start to fix this would be appreciated.

Specifications:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
- mobo: M4A89GTD-PRO
- BIOS: 2101
- CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor
- RAM: 6111188 kB
- HDD: ATA OCZ-VERTEX3
- GPU: GeForce GT 440
- Mouse / keyboard: M510, K350 single unifying receiver

edit - I have tried several different galaxy S4 phones (My employer provides cells to all engineers / managers) and the same error appears on all of them. (Well, almost the same error - the last 3 digits appear to just be random numbers; not sure if there's a way to decipher them.)  These phones are running Ice Cream, Jelly, and KKat - no difference at all.  Have also tried multiple cables and multiple USB ports.

**Edit:** - I tried downloading the latest libmtp (1.1.7) but to no avail.  mtp-detect says it is unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.  Plugging in the phone still pops up:

> Unable to mount SAMSUNG Android
>   Unable to open MTP device '[usb:003,007]'

only the final number (007) appears to be a counter; over the long weekend I apparently tried 149 different times to get this to work.

This was not an issue at all in 12.04.

**Edit 2:**  I spent countless hours over the past weekend banging away trying to get this to work.  I booted to a live CD of 12.04, and it works flawlessly.  I booted to a live CD of 12.10, and it works flawlessly.  I booted to a freshly-downloaded live CD of 14.04.1, and it does not work at all.  Obviously, something was changed somewhere in 14.04.  I found a huge number of posts from Google about this; it is a very prevalent issue.  Why did Ubuntu choose to deploy 14.04 with so many things broken that used to work just fine?

**Edit 3:**  Just had a thought... since Ubuntu has so many issues with 'read only' file system creation on USB devices, is there a connection with this issue?

** Edit 4:**  Just on a lark, I decided to try plugging in to each and every USB port on the machine.  "Unable to open MTP device '[usb:003,007]'" still appears on every one, but the numeric values are different - just wanted to ensure I ruled out a bad USB port.

**Edit 5:**  This Friday will be 30 days since installing 14.04.  Does anybody please have any ideas as to what is causing this?  If I cannot get viable solutions to a majority of the issues I'm having by Friday, then this weekend will be spent wiping 14.04 and going back to Win 7.  I think devoting countless hours to 14.04 over the course of a month is more than enough time to try and get it working.  As it stands now, I still have not risked installing any software beyond what is installed with the ISO that I downloaded.  I really need a trustworthy OS.

**Last Update**  This issue is still unresolved, and after a month of messing with it I am giving up and wiping 14.04 from my system.

Comment: "And yes, the phone is in USB debug mode." That's unnecessary. I compared `69-libmtp.rules` from trusty with utopic and couldn't find anything related in there, but I also don't know the vendor and product ID of the device (and could find it quickly either), so I don't know if it's in there or not. Version numbers of the [corresponding package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmtp-common) don't differ much, but that's where I would start digging. Or try to install the utopic packages reboot and check again.

Comment: The 'debug mode' switch came from a lot of digging through the android sites; the gvfs-mtp solution used to be the accepted answer, but not any longer because "newer versions of ubuntu should be fixed."  However, according to an android developer site, this is still a major issue for them, and they are all pointing to ubuntu as the source of the issue as this affects multiple devices and multiple versions of android.  Thanks for the libmtp suggestion; I'll check there after I get a few more issues straightened out.

Comment: Running `sudo service udev restart` seems to have so far solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gvfs:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gvfs
```

I had trouble with mine at first, but after installing `gvfs`, its working fine. Also wise to reboot first and then plug in your samsung!

> GVfs is a userspace virtual filesystem designed to work with the I/O abstraction of GIO (a library availible in GLib >= 2.15.1). It installs several modules that are automatically used by applications using the APIs of libgio. There is also FUSE support that allows applications not using GIO to access the GVfs filesystems. - [Projects/gvfs - GNOME Wiki!](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/gvfs)

Comment: first line returned:  '13.10 (Saucy) and newer versions of Ubuntu contain all of these changes, so you don't need to use this ppa any more.'  Second line returned two 'Failed to fetch' warnings from this ppa, third line returned 'gvfs is already the newest version.   And the error message is now "Unable to mount SAMSUNG Android Unable to open MTP device '[usb:003,008]'"

Comment: @snurfle Yeah just searched for it. Completely missed that change.