# Can't access any files on Android phone connected to USB port

Tags: 20.04, usb, kubuntu, android

I'm trying to back up my user files from my Android phone (recommended before a possible phone repair) into free space on my Kubuntu 20.04.3 desktop system, but although the notifier tells me when I've connected the phone via USB cable (through a 4-port USB hub that works fine for other things including writing SD cards for my 3D printer, with a cable that the phone accepts for "charging rapidly" though I don't often try to transfer data), any attempt to access files on the phone results in an error message.

I found [an answer relevant to older versions of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566640/why-cant-ubuntu-14-04-access-the-files-on-my-android-phone) recommending installation of `gvfs` tools, but comments indicate it's no longer needed since 13.10, as all of those tools are included in newer versions.  Presuming it's relevant, I also can't download photos from my phone.

Phone is a first-gen Google Pixel, approaching four years old, and 100% functional aside from greatly reduced battery life, possible accelerometer issues (screen rotation is intermittent), and possible light level sensing issues (screen auto brightness mostly dosen't work, possibly due to a dirty Otter Box).

Do I need to do something special to transfer files (photos, music, downloaded game .apk files) from the phone to the Kubuntu system?

Comment: Many phones are very "picky". Try the original cable or a known good quality cable and, of course, avoid hubs.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the phone to get more information. Immediately after connecting, `ls -lrt /dev` will show the device name. [Edit] your Question to show us.

Comment: It has been my experience that I have to change a setting on my phone to get my computer to see it as a storage device. On my Android phone it's under Settings > Connected devices > USB preferences > File transfer.

Comment: @KneadToKnow I don't find anything related to USB Preferences anywhere under Settings.  Connected Devices only seems to be about Bluetooth.  Phone has Android 10, might be a version difference.  'Doh!  Only shows when the cable is connected!

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm Android 10 also. I find that the USB options only appear when I have a USB cable plugged in, if that helps at all.

Comment: Yep, @KneadToKnow, see edited comment.  That was all I needed, files appear to be accessible now.  You could/should make that an answer -- few folks who aren't Android power users use all the features of their smart phones...

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion. This is my first Answer here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A setting on the phone governs how the computer interacts with it. On my Android 10 phone it's under Settings > Connected devices > USB preferences > File transfer.

Note that to see the USB preferences, it appears that you have to have a USB cable plugged in.